# using IOC container with IdentityFactory Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I am trying to understand the UserManagerFactory middleware explained here [per request lifetime management for usermanager](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/12/per-request-lifetime-management-for-usermanager-class-in-asp-net-identity.aspx).

I created this class which I am calling from the Startup Configuration method

```
public class CustomUserManagerProvider
{
    public static CustomUserStore<CustomUser> CreateCustomUserStore()
    {
        return new CustomUserStore<CustomUser>(/*Need to inject dependencies here*/);
    }

    public static CustomUserManager CreateCustomUserManager(IdentityFactoryOptions<CustomUserManager> options,
        IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new CustomUserManager(context.Get<CustomUserStore<CustomUser>>());
    }
}
```

And the Startup Configuration

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(CustomUserManagerProvider.CreateCustomUserStore);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<IngramUserManager>(CustomUserManagerProvider.CreateCustomUserManager);
        ////....Other things
    }
```

Now, My CustomUserStore has some dependencies which I want to inject in the constructor.

The composition root of the IOC container knows how to resolve these dependencies.

How do I make the `CustomUserManagerProvider` DI container aware(If that makes sense)...

Although this works

```
public static CustomUserStore<CustomUser> CreateCustomUserStore()
    {
        var dependency = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISomeDependency>();          
        return new CustomUserStore<CustomUser>(dependency);
    }
```

But, I was trying to avoid the service locator (anti)pattern. Is this my only option, Is this even right??

I am using Ninject.

Cant I just create a UserManager in requestScope in the composition root and inject into the controllers, wont that be the same thing?

In a web app, is CreatePerOwinContext same as creating InRequestScope?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can inject the UserManager into your controllers a different way if you like, there's nothing that requires using the CreatePerOwinContext/IdentityFactoryMiddleware.

Comment: Trailmax offers a step by step about how to convert the Identity project template to one using Unity for DI here; http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/ There are a couple of gotchas he picks up on so it's worth a read. i.e. you CAN'T entirely delete all your app.CreatePerOwinContexts for UserManager. You're still going to need a app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>()); in Startup.auth.

Comment: Using ILSpy, the only call to `OwinContext.Get<T>()` that I see is in the `SecurityStampValidator` (via a call to `OwinContext.GetUserManager`). Since `SecurityStampValidator` is only used with `CookieAuthenticationProvider` then it should be safe to skip calling `CreatePerOwinContext` if you're using WebApi without cookies.